# Error for if statement condition in adder/subtractor

Tags: vhdl

I am new to the VHDL language, so please bear with me and please help me out.

I have written code for a addition/subtraction unit which will operate on signed integer but at the "if else" part in the last, the compiler is giving an error.

```
library ieee;  
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity adder is  
port(A,B : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  
     SUM : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);  
     mode: in  std_logic_vector(0 downto 0));
end adder; 


architecture behave of adder is  

component xorgate is
port( p,q: in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        r: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
end component;

signal a1,b1,sum1,output1,mode1:integer;
signal tmp: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
variable output: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);


begin
u1: xorgate  port map (B, mode, output);
output1 <= to_integer(signed (output));
a1      <= to_integer(signed(A));
b1      <= to_integer(signed(B));
mode1   <= to_integer(signed(mode));

process(a1,output1,b1,tmp,mode1)
begin
if ( mode1 <= '1') then
sum1 <= a1 + output1 ;
else
sum1 <= a1 + b1;
end if; 

tmp <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(sum1,4));
SUM <= tmp( 3 downto 0);
end process;
end behave;
```

**XST Error Message:**

> ERROR: HDLCompiler:1731 - "E:\XILINX PROGRAM\FULLADD\FULLADD.vhd" Line 31: found '0' definitions of operator "<=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "<="
>   ERROR: HDLCompiler:854 - "E:\XILINX PROGRAM\FULLADD\FULLADD.vhd" Line 11: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

Comment: So there are two additional errors in your code preventing successful analysis, bot associated with your `u1` port map. First `mode`'s length doesn't match the `xorgate actual `q`'s length and second you've declared `output` as a variable, it should be a signal. There's also no sign of the '+ 1' for two's complementing `output`, can you show us `xorgate`? It's likely you can have a single data path for `b1`/`output` into the actual adder, also adding 1 for the carry in based on `mode(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

Line 31: `if ( mode1 <= '1') then`

you meant: `if ( mode1 = 1) then`

Line 11: This just means that because of the previous error, the compiler 'gave up'.

Comment: mode1 is an integer, so it should be compared to `1` not `'1'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `<=` operator in `mode1 <= '1'` is less-than-or-equal compare of integer with `'1'`, which have no definition, thus the `found '0' definitions of operator "<="`.  Change `'1'` to `simply the integer literal`1`.

Other issues with the code are listed below.

The ´variable output: ...´ must be `signal output:` when `output` is used as actual for in port map for `xorgate`.  In typical design you don't have variables in the declaration section, between `begin` and `end`, of an architecture.

Length of `mode` is only 1 `std_logic` (bit), but actual for mode in `xorgate  port map`, which is `q` in `xorgate`, is 4 bits.  You probably meant to make `mode` as `3 downto 0` in the port declaration of `adder`, since compare like `mode1 <= 1` will be trivial true if `mode` is 1 bit.

The intermediate integer signals named `*1` and other signal are actually not required if the process uses `signed` additions from `numeric_std` package like:

```
process(A, B, mode, output) is
begin
  if signed(mode) <= 1 then
    SUM <= std_logic_vector(signed(A) + signed(output));
  else
    SUM <= std_logic_vector(signed(A) + signed(B));
  end if;
end process;
```

And this can even be reduced to the below, with only `output` as intermediate signal:

```
SUM <= std_logic_vector(signed(A) + signed(output)) when (signed(mode) <= 1)
       else std_logic_vector(signed(A) + signed(B));
```

Finally, if `mode` is to be treaded like unsigned, then replace with `unsigned(mode)`, since `unsigned` is also defined in the `numeric_std` package.

Answer (score 0):

The puzzle is probably why the error message is about failure to find an overloaded operator

`'1'` has at least two definitions, first as a character literal, then as a bit literal. Neither of these have a `<=` operator comparing them with type Integer, and *that*'s why the compiler gave up.

If you had used an integer literal `1` instead, the compiler could have found a `<=` operator easily... so `if mode1 <= '1' then` would work.

Alternatively, you could write your own `<=` operator accepting inputs of these two types and returning a boolean :

```
function "<=" (a : Integer; b : Bit) return Boolean is ...
```

While it would work, it would also deserve a slap on the wrist!